# Given a geotiff file, how does one find the single pixel closest to a given latitude/longitude?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

I have a geotiff file that I'm opening with gdal in Python, and I need to find the single pixel closest to a specified latitude/longitude. I was previously working with an unrelated file type for similar data, so I'm completely new to both gdal and geotiff.

How does one do this?  What I have so far is

```
import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('foo.tiff')
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
gp = ds.GetProjection()
data = np.array(ds.ReadAsArray())
print(gt)
print(gp)
```

which produces (for my files)

```
(-3272421.457337171, 2539.703, 0.0, 3790842.1060354356, 0.0, -2539.703)
```

and

```
PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",DATUM["unnamed",SPHEROID["Sphere",6371200,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",25],PARAMETER["central_meridian",265],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",25],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",25],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Ideally, there'd be a single simple function call, and it would also return an indication whether the specified location falls outside the bounds of the raster.

My fallback is to obtain a grid from another source containing the latitudes and longitudes for each pixel and then do a brute force search for the desired location, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way.

Note: I think what I'm trying to do is equivalent to the command line

```
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 foo.tif <longitude> <latitude>
```

which returns results like

```
Report:
  Location: (1475P,1181L)
  Band 1:
    Value: 66
```

This suggests to me that the functionality is probably already in the `gdal` module, if I can just find the right method to call.

Comment: I would use rioxarray. See the maintainer of that library's answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358058/15001. You are essentially transforming your lon/lat coordinate to an x/y coordinate in the geotiff's coordinate space (which seems to also be lon/lat in your case) then using rioxarray to convert that to a row/col index. If this option performs slower there are more manual calculations you could do that would perform better. CC @snowman2.

Comment: Thanks @djhoese. Turns out both rioxarray and rasterio require something called PEP 517, which I don't have.  "Could not build wheels for rasterio which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"   Researching now whether that's something that can easily be installed on my aarch64 machine.
Failing that, I'm back to my fallback plan of simply loading the grid of locations and searching.  I'm a bit shocked that the gdal library doesn't have a built-in solution to this basic problem, especially given that the command line utility does.

Comment: On closer look, the actual problem installing rasterio seems to be something with the gcc call:
  gcc -pthread  ... -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -n1 .2-a+fp16+rcpc+dotprod+crypto ... -O2 -n1 .2-a+fp16+rcpc+dotprod+crypto -isystem /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/grib2/include -fPIC ...
  gcc: error: .2-a+fp16+rcpc+dotprod+crypto: No such file or directory
  gcc: error: .2-a+fp16+rcpc+dotprod+crypto: No such file or directory
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-n1’; did you mean ‘-n’?
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

Comment: 1. If you don't have a version of `pip` and `setuptools` that supports PEP 517, you need to upgrade. This PEP is old enough now and well supported enough that most modern versions of packages are using it.
2. You should be able to install gdal, rioxarray, and rasterio from conda-forge.
3. There may be a way to do this directly in GDAL's Python bindings, but I don't know it and GDAL's bindings are not very pythonic. Rasterio does a better job of wrapping the C/C++ library so you could probably use that directly I'm just less familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need two steps:

1. Convert the lat/lon point to the raster-projection
2. Convert the mapx/mapy (in raster proj) to pixel coordinates

Given the code you already posted above, defining both projection systems can be done with:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

point_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
point_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # hardcode for lon/lat

# GDAL>=3: make sure it's x/y
# see https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn
point_srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)     

file_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
file_srs.ImportFromWkt(gp)
```

Creating the coordinate transformation, and using it to convert the point from lon/lat to mapx/mapy coordinates (whatever projection it is) with:

```
ct = osr.CoordinateTransformation(point_srs, file_srs)

point_x = -114.06138 # lon
point_y = 51.03163  # lat
mapx, mapy, z = ct.TransformPoint(point_x, point_y)
```

To go from map coordinates to pixel coordinates, the geotransform needs to be inverted first. And can then be used to retrieve the pixel coordinates like:

```
gt_inv = gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt)
pixel_x, pixel_y = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_inv, mapx, mapy)
```

Rounding those pixel coordinates should allow you to use them for indexing the data array. You might need to clip them if the point you're querying is outside the raster.

```
# round to pixel
pixel_x = round(pixel_x)
pixel_y = round(pixel_y)

# clip to file extent
pixel_x = max(min(pixel_x, width-1), 0)
pixel_y = max(min(pixel_y, height-1), 0)

pixel_data = data[pixel_y, pixel_x]
```

Comment: Your code sample depends on several 'osr' calls and classes, but there's no corresponding import statement. Where do these come from?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the imports. It's all standard GDAL. You can import `osr` from `osgeo` as you (should) do with the `gdal` import. But you can also access it as a submodule of `gdal` itself, for example with `gdal.osr.SpatialReference()`. That submodule method also works for `gdal.ogr.` which I didn't use in this case.